# Where has the "Show in Viewport" option in the 2.8 branch of Animation-Nodes gone?

Tags: animation-nodes

I may be missing something, but the "Show in the Viewport" option that was available under "Advanced Node Setting" for an input data, is no longer there.

Is there a way to get the data input interact at the viewport level?

Comment: There is Viewport Input node to get the viewport inputs and inputs are available in the 3D viewport in N-panel under "AN" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option has been replaced by a more advanced node called the *Viweport Input* node. Every *Viweport Input* node creates an input box in the AN panel, the name of the input box is defined by the label of the *Viweport Input* node that defines it. The boxes can be minimized and you can change the order of inputs as you wish from the N menu. For instance, we have here two *Viweport Input* nodes defining two input boxes:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Huge Thanks Omar.  Your answer solve the issue.  Gil

Comment: @ISNBLENDER Please accept the answer if it answers your question.